# Rotating matrices

Tags: c#, winforms, math, matrix

## Objectives

Imagine that, we have matrix like

```
a11 a12 a13
a21 a22 a23
a31 a32 a33
```

What I want to do is, from textbox value rotate this matrix so that, for example if I write 2 and press <kbd>rotate</kbd>, program must keep both diagonal values of matrix (in this case a11, a22, a33, a13, a31) and rotate 2 times clockwise other values. So result must be like

```
a11 a32 a13
a23 a22 a21
a31 a12 a33
```

It must work for all `N x N` size matrices, and as you see every 4 rotation takes matrix into default state.

## What I've done

So idea is like that, I have 2 forms. First takes size of matrix (1 value, for example if it's 5, it generates 5x5 matrix). When I press <kbd>OK</kbd> it generates second forms textbox matrix like that

Form 1 code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int matrixSize;
        matrixSize = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(matrixSize);
        form2.Width = matrixSize * 50 + 100;
        form2.Height = matrixSize *60 + 200;
        form2.Show();            
        //this.Hide();
    }
```

Form 2 code generates textbox matrix from given value and puts random values into this fields

```
public Form2(int matrSize)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            InitializeComponent();
            TextBox[] MatrixNodes = new TextBox[matrSize*matrSize];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= matrSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= matrSize; j++)
                {
                    var tb = new TextBox();                    
                    int num = r.Next(1, 1000);
                    MatrixNodes[counter] = tb;
                    tb.Name = string.Format("Node_{0}{1}", i, j);
                    Debug.Write(string.Format("Node_{0}{1}", i, j));
                    tb.Text = num.ToString();
                    tb.Location = new Point(j * 50, i * 50);
                    tb.Width = 30;
                    tb.Visible = true;
                    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(tb);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Form 2 has 1 textbox for controlling rotation (others are generated on the fly, programmatically). What I want to do is, when I enter rotation count and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on this textbox, I want to rotate textbox matrix as I explained above. Can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's not about 3x3 matrix - it's just sample. Application is about NxN. And, I think your commebt is nonsense

Comment: Copy both diagonals to separate array, transpose the matrix as many times as you need and replace resulting diagonals with saved ones.

Comment: @StaWho please explain in code

Comment: @StaWho Transposing isn't the same as a rotation.

Comment: @heron Answer posted.

Comment: Do I understand you want rotation to be applied only on the column and row that contain the number you entered? In this case, the 2nd column and row?

Comment: @LightStriker when I enter 2, it must rotate matrix clockwise 2 times keeping diagonal elements

Comment: @heron Could you give an example in a 4x4 or 5x4 matrices? Because right now I'm simply not sure what is your "diagonal elements" and what falls or not into that category.

Comment: @LightStriker I agree it's a bit ambiguous, but see my answer for a likely explanation. I think it's likely, anyway : )

Comment: @LightStriker re read question. It's only about n x n matrices. not n x m   
Look at this: screencast.com/t/PpJxE1GK0853 . All blacks are diagonal elements and must be same. All red triangles must be rotated clockwise. So result of this rotation must be pastebin.com/QZhmxrGt

Comment: @heron I asked for a 4x4 for a good reason... What is the valid diagonal in a even matrix? Or does it work only for odd matrix?

Comment: @LightStriker The primary diagonal and secondary diagonal are both well-defined for any square matrix, whether N is even or odd. Rotating `{{00,01,02,03},{10,11,12,13},{20,21,22,23},{30,31,32,33}}` once yields `{{00,20,10,03},{31,11,12,01},{32,21,22,02},{30,23,13,33}}`

Answer (score 9):

Copy both diagonals to separate arrays, then rotate your matrix and replace diagonals. Below code shows each step:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int matrixSize = 3;
        string[,] matrix = new string[matrixSize,matrixSize];

        //create square matrix
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                matrix[x, y] = "a" + (x + 1).ToString() + (y + 1).ToString();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Base square matrix");

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {              
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[x, y] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //copy diagonals
        string[] leftDiagonal = new string[matrixSize];
        string[] rightDiagonal = new string[matrixSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            leftDiagonal[x] = matrix[x, x];
            rightDiagonal[x] = matrix[matrixSize - 1 - x, x];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Diagonals");

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; ++x)
        {
            Console.Write(leftDiagonal[x] + " " + rightDiagonal[x] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //rotate matrix
        string[,] rotatedMatrix = new string[matrixSize, matrixSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                rotatedMatrix[x, y] = matrix[matrixSize - y - 1, x];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Rotated");

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(rotatedMatrix[x, y] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //rotate matrix again
        string[,] rotatedMatrixAgain = new string[matrixSize, matrixSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                rotatedMatrixAgain[x, y] = rotatedMatrix[matrixSize - y - 1, x];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Rotated again");

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(rotatedMatrixAgain[x, y] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //replace diagonals
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            rotatedMatrixAgain[x, x] = leftDiagonal[x];
            rotatedMatrixAgain[matrixSize - 1 - x, x] = rightDiagonal[x];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Completed" + Environment.NewLine);

        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(rotatedMatrixAgain[x, y] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need form, not console. Please help me in forms, I'm newbie to c#

Comment: The code in answer is not meant to be finished product. It verbosely explains the algorithm, which achieves your required result. Specific implementation, regardless of framework, is entirely dependent on application design and in your case it means if I implemented this in Forms for you, I would deprive you from taking an amazing journey from frustration, through understanding to achievement :)

Comment: I offer 50 bounty for what you mean finished product

Comment: You need to decouple your user interface from your logic. Good programming wouldn't care whether you're working with a console or forms, or even web. Try building a class that does just the logic you want. Then post it here if it doesn't work. You have something to reference.

Comment: @heron You're going to have a hard time getting anyone to write a finished product for you. I think this is the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: @Telthien I don't need console solution.

Comment: @heron The algorithm you ask for is *not* dependent on the framework used to run it. You can use this answer with a few tweaks to do what you want. If you are unable to do this yourself, you may want to google for a site which advertises consultants for hire instead of using a free Q&A service like SO.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know C#, so I can only give a suggestion in pseudocode:

**Input:** An N by N matrix `in`

**Output:** The input matrix rotated as described in the OP `out`

```
for i = 1 to N
    for j = 1 to N
        if N - j != i and i != j // Do not change values on either diagonal
            out[j][N-i] = in[i][j]
        else
            out[i][j] = in[i][j]
```

Disclaimer: This algorithm is untested. I suggest you use a debugger to check that it works as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite an unorthodox UI presentation, but you're not too far off in terms of being able to achieve your functionality. Instead of a linear array, a rectangular array will make your job much easier. The actual rotation could be implemented with a for loop repeating a single rotation (which would be implemented as in the `case 1` code), but I've decided to combine them into the four possible cases. This actually allows you to enter a negative number for number of rotations. Which reminds me, you really should do more error checking. At least protect against `int.Parse` throwing an exception both places it's used (with a try catch block or by switching to `int.TryParse`) and make sure it returns a meaningful number (greater than `0`, possibly set a reasonable maximum other than `int.MaxValue`) for `matrixSize` in `button1_Click`.

```
namespace RotatingMatrices
{
    public class Form2 : Form
    {
        // note these class fields
        private TextBox[,] matrixNodes;
        private int matrixSize;

        public Form2(int matrSize)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // note these inits
            matrixSize = matrSize;
            matrixNodes = new TextBox[matrixSize, matrixSize];

            Random r = new Random();

            // note the new loop limits
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
                {
                    var tb = new TextBox();                    
                    int num = r.Next(1, 1000);

                    // note the change in indexing
                    matrixNodes[i,j] = tb;
                    tb.Name = string.Format("Node_{0}_{1}", i, j);
                    Debug.Write(string.Format("Node_{0}_{1}", i, j));
                    tb.Text = num.ToString();
                    tb.Location = new Point(j * 50, i * 50);
                    tb.Width = 30;
                    tb.Visible = true;
                    this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonRotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[,] matrix = new string[matrixSize, matrixSize];
            int rotations = (4 + int.Parse(textBoxRotations.Text)) % 4; // note the addition of and mod by 4

            switch(rotations)
            {
                case 1: // rotate clockwise
                    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
                        {
                            matrix[j, matrixSize - i - 1] = matrixNodes[i, j].Text;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:  // rotate 180 degrees
                    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
                        {
                            matrix[i, j] = matrixNodes[matrixSize - i - 1, matrixSize - j - 1].Text;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: // rotate counter-clockwise
                    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
                        {
                            matrix[i, j] = matrixNodes[j, matrixSize - i - 1].Text;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default: // do nothing
                   return;
            }

            // restore diagonals
            for(int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
            {
                matrix[i, i] = matrixNodes[i, i].Text;
                matrix[i, matrixSize - i - 1] = matrixNodes[i, matrixSize - i - 1].Text;
            }

            // write strings back to text boxes
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++)
                {
                   matrixNodes[i, j].Text = matrix[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interresting... But what about even matrices? What is the valid diagonal in a 4x4? (Note that I didn't ask for a 5x5 because I needed the most ambiguous example clarified)

Comment: Look at this: http://screencast.com/t/PpJxE1GK0853 . All blacks are diagonal elements and must be same. All red triangles must be rotated clockwise. So result of this rotation must be http://pastebin.com/QZhmxrGt

Comment: @LightStriker I'll updata my answer with an example of what I think a `4 x 4` rotation should look like in a bit

Comment: @heron Clearly I didn't understand your request correctly the first time, thank you for the additional information. I've updated my answer accordingly and expanded it to include the interaction with the form.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to tackle the issue using a `listView` instead of a text box, which makes the logic easier for me. Using this method, I was able to think of the matrix as successive boxes.  I start on the outside and move in toward the middle, changing the size of my box each time.

Also, rather than using two forms, I use one.  At the top I have a textbox where the user enters the size they want the array to be, and a button labeled "Fill" (button2).  And at the bottom I have a textbox where the user enters the degree of rotation. When they click "Rotate," it kicks off a process of adding values to linked lists, combining and shifting the list, and then writing back out to the matrix.  I'm sure I made it more convoluted than it has to be, but it was a great learning exercise.

After looking over jerry's code above, I think I'm going to look into rectangular arrays.  :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Recycle
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public int size;
    public LinkedList<string> topRight = new LinkedList<string>();
    public LinkedList<string> bottomLeft = new LinkedList<string>();
    public LinkedList<string> myMatrix = new LinkedList<string>();
    public LinkedList<string> shiftMatrix = new LinkedList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Clear();

        size = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int c = 0;
        int q = 0;
        int w = 0;
        string[] content = new string[size];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {
            listView1.Columns.Add("", 25);
        }

        for (q = 0; q < size; q++) 
        {
            for (w = 0; w < size; w++)
            {
                content[w] = rnd.Next(9,100).ToString();
            }

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(content);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

    }

    public bool iseven(int size)
    {
        if (size % 2 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.Items.Count < 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Matrix cannot be rotated.");
            return;
        }

        bool even = false;
        int shift = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //amount to shift by
        int box = listView1.Items.Count - 1; //size of box
        int half = Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Items.Count / 2);
        int corner = 0; //inside corner of box

        if (shift > listView1.Items.Count)
        {
            shift = shift % ((listView1.Items.Count - 2) * 4);
        }

        do
        {
            eachPass(shift, box, corner);
            ++corner;
            --box;
        } while (box >= half + 1);

    }

    public void eachPass(int shift, int box, int corner)
    {
        int x;
        int i;

        //Read each non-diagonal value into one of two lists
        for (x = corner + 1; x < box; x++)
        {
            topRight.AddLast(listView1.Items[corner].SubItems[x].Text);
        }

        x = box;

        for (i = corner + 1; i < box; i++)
        {
            topRight.AddLast(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[x].Text);
        }

        for (x = box - 1; x  > corner; x--)
        {
            bottomLeft.AddLast(listView1.Items[box].SubItems[x].Text);
        }

        x = corner;

        for (i = box - 1; i > corner; i--)
        {
            bottomLeft.AddLast(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[x].Text);
        }

        string myTest = "";

        //join the two lists, so they can be shifted
        foreach (string tR in topRight)
        {
            myMatrix.AddLast(tR);
        }

        foreach (string bL in bottomLeft)
        {
            myMatrix.AddLast(bL);
        }

        int sh;

        //shift the list using another list
        for (sh = shift; sh < myMatrix.Count; sh++)
        {
            shiftMatrix.AddLast(myMatrix.ElementAt(sh));
        }

        for (sh = 0; sh < shift; sh++)
        {
            shiftMatrix.AddLast(myMatrix.ElementAt(sh));
        }

        //we need the sizes of the current lists
        int trCnt = topRight.Count;
        int blCnt = bottomLeft.Count;

        //clear them for reuse
        topRight.Clear();
        bottomLeft.Clear();

        int s;

        //put the shifted values back
        for (s = 0; s < trCnt; s++)
        {
            topRight.AddLast(shiftMatrix.ElementAt(s));
        }

        for (s = blCnt; s < shiftMatrix.Count; s++)
        {
            bottomLeft.AddLast(shiftMatrix.ElementAt(s));
        }

        int tRn = 0;
        int bLn = 0;

        //write each non-diagonal value from one of two lists
        for (x = corner + 1; x < box; x++)
        {
            listView1.Items[corner].SubItems[x].Text = topRight.ElementAt(tRn);
            ++tRn;
        }

        x = box;

        for (i = corner + 1; i < box; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems[x].Text = topRight.ElementAt(tRn);
            ++tRn;
        }

        for (x = box - 1; x > corner; x--)
        {
            listView1.Items[box].SubItems[x].Text = bottomLeft.ElementAt(bLn);
            ++bLn;
        }

        x = corner;

        for (i = box - 1; i > corner; i--)
        {
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems[x].Text = bottomLeft.ElementAt(bLn);
            ++bLn;
        }

        myMatrix.Clear();
        shiftMatrix.Clear();
        topRight.Clear();
        bottomLeft.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```